# filePath from JFileChooser is null

Tags: java, objectoutputstream

I am currently working on a Project and would like to save an object to a file with `ObjectOutputStream` to a location the user chooses with the help of a `JFileChooser`. But the object is always saved to the root directory of the program into the file named "null" (`%ProjectDirectory%/null`).

Here's my method `saveObjects`, which saves a `LinkedList` of objects to a file:

```
public void saveObjects(String filePath) {
    try {
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(filePath);
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(os);
        oos.writeObject(oceanObjects);
        oos.close();
        os.close();
    } catch(IOException e) {
        System.err.println(e);
    }
}
```

This instruction calls the method `saveObject` with the `filepath` as a parameter (`filePath` is a String; I already tried to use a File)

```
saveObjects(view.getFilePath());
```

`view` is an instance of `OceanLifeView` and `view.getFilePath()` is a getter-method of that class that returns the path where the file should be saved (as a String).

getFilePath() looks like this:

```
public String getFilePath() {
    return filePath;
}
```

And my OceanLifeView like this:

```
OceanLifeView(String title, int type) {
    if(...) {
        ...
    }else if (title.equals("fileChooser")) {
        fileChooser = new JFileChooser();
        fileChooser.setFileSelectionMode(FILES_ONLY);

        if (type == 0) {
            //Load Button functions
            System.out.println("De-Serialisation started fileChooserGUI!");
            returnVal = fileChooser.showOpenDialog(fileChooser);
        } else {
            //Save Button functions
            System.out.println("Serialisation started fileChooserGUI!");
            returnVal = fileChooser.showSaveDialog(fileChooser);
        }

        if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
            filePath = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
        }
    }
}
```

I would be very thankful to anybody who can share some insight for the problem I encounter or mistake I made implementing this functionality.

Comment: Does`view.getFilePath()` return the same `filePath` String you assigned at the end?

Comment: @MNos: Yes, I initialized filePath outside the OceanLifeView constructor in the OceanLifeView class to access it with a getter method.

Comment: Can you please add `System.out.println("filePath: " + filePath);` at the first line of `saveObjects` method and provide us with the output?

Comment: Your problem is in the swing code not the `saveObjects()`, you give it `"null"`. (BTW: if you add the println the way it was proposed it does not create a NPE).

Comment: I've added some `println()` instructions and realized that `view` is the instance of the MainGUI and I need to use `fileChooser`: Therefor I need to use `saveObjects(fileChooser.getFilePath());` instead of  `saveObjects(view.getFilePath());`. The instance view never sets `filePath` to anything. Now everything works as intended :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks as if you are passing files relative path to FileOutputStream constructor.

Probable cause of that is that filePath is calculated as `filePath = selectedFile.getPath()` instead it should be calculated like this:

```
File selectedFile = fileChooser.getSelectedFile();
String filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
```

Comment: Doing that throws me this error: Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Can you send part of stack trace - from this context I don't understand where exactly exception happened. My guess would be that fileChooser is not initialised at the time code was run - but without exception stack trace this is only guessing.

Comment: Okay ... as it seams `String filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();` doesn't saves the file path into `filePath`. So `view.getFilePath()` returns `null`